# How i can get value from s:checkbox

Tags: struts2

i want to get value from table using s:checkbox 
i create this app using struts2
My code is as follows:
testAction.java

```
public class test extends ActionSupport{
    private String id;
    private List<String> colors;
    private String yourColor;

    public String getYourColor() {
        return yourColor;
    }
    public void setYourColor(String yourColor) {
        this.yourColor = yourColor;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<String> getColors() {
        return colors;
    }
    public void setColors(List<String> colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }
     private List<ColorBean> list ;

     public List<ColorBean> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String display() {
        return NONE;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
 <action name="testAction" class="action.testAction" method="display">
    <result name="none" type="tiles">index</result>
 </action>  
 <action name="resultAction" class="action.testAction">
    <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

index.jsp

```
<s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/">
<table id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>sheck</th>
           <th>IF</th>
           <th>CINOURC</th>
           <th>NOMOURC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="list">
        <tr>
           <td>
              <s:checkbox   name="yourColor" 
                  fieldValue="%{list}"  theme="simple" />
           </td>
           <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
           <td><s:property value="cin" /></td>
           <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

result.jsp

```
    <h2>
        value : <s:property value="yourColor"/>
    </h2>
```

the problem is when i receive the value in result page i receive an object like

```
[bean.RarBean@42a3fe79, bean.RarBean@2d2cfd76, bean.RarBean@54e8f278]
```

and when i try to do something like this

```
<h2>
   value : <s:property value="yourColor.id"/>
</h2>
```

i receive nothing ..
how i can handle this problem

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Hint: `fieldValue="%{list}"` is the culprit

Comment: What do you mean by fieldValue is the culprit ??